# Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.model.user out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, model, rest-client

I am passing json string from restclient to resteasy webservice for model object user.

I have set Content-Type=application/json

and my json string in body is as follows,

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "email": "email",
    "add": [
        {
            "lastName": "lastName",
            "firstName": "firstName"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "firstName",
            "lastName": "lastName"
        }
    ]
}
```

If i remove add array object as below, then i am getting the response as expected.

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "email": "email",
}
```

When i try to send add array , server is throwing an exception saying,

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.model.add out of START_ARRAY token
```

I tried this way also, but its not working,

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "email": "email",
     "lastName": "Something Four",
     "firstName": "Something Five"
}
```

Then it is giving below error,

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "lastName" (Class com.model.user), not marked as ignorable
```

My model objects are below,

```
public class user implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="Id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=true, length=60)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="Id", nullable=false)
    private add add;
}



public class add implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="LastName", nullable=true, length=128)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="FirstName", nullable=true, length=128)
    private String firstName;

}
```

My service class

```
@POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
     public Response addAccount(@FormParam("id") String id,
             @FormParam("lastName") String lastName,
             @FormParam("firstName") String firstName,
             @FormParam("email") String email{



            user.setId(id); 
            add.setLastName(lastName);
            add.setFirstName(firstName);
            user.setEmailAddress(email);
}
```

Can anyone help me in passing one model object inside other model object as an array in json string?

Comment: Please show us the JSON you are sending. Jackson is telling you here this is not a JSON array.

Comment: this is the json i am using ,{
    "id": "100",
    "email": "email",
    "add": [
        {
            "lastName": "lastName",
            "firstName": "firstName"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "firstName",
            "lastName": "lastName"
        }
    ]
} i have validated it using jsonlint and its showing as valid json.\

Comment: That is not the question. I ask what you send as the _add_ array you have removed.

Comment: How do you explain your first message then? "Can not deserialize instance of com.model.add out of START_ARRAY token" <-- this means Jackson expects a JSON object but you send a JSON array

Comment: Read your second message again, it also says: "Unrecognized field "lastName" (Class com.model.user), not marked as ignorable" <-- this gives you a hint: it MAY be ignored, just use the right tool to have it ignored

Comment: As a workaround, do not remove the array entirely, just empty it

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, the solution i found; the getters and setters were missing in my model class.
Probably this will solve this issue.

Comment: This is not answer. So write this in comment section. See this link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer